# I can't restore my iPhone from the latest back up

Tags: iphone, restore, error

I'm unable to restore my iPhone.  I'm getting an error about an incorrect password.  First it backed up some stuff and not other stuff.  I went to the Apple store and they told me to delete this iPhone and try to back it up again because it never finished restoring.

Now it tells me I need a password and every password I've entered has been wrong.

Comment: The two that it might be are your passcode you use to unlock the phone or your Apple ID password. Perhaps bring it back to the Apple Store?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue "Forgot Apple ID or password?" on https://www.icloud.com/ open this link on your computer. Hope you get your password back!